# Rewrite the search page to use an appended slug + parameter

Tags: hooks, url-rewriting, search, actions, rewrite-rules

I have two URLs that handle search

- `~/search/` = main search page
- `~/?s=` = results page

What I want: to have one search page where the search parameter for the results page appends to the search page base.

For example: `~/search/?s=`

I've read & tried a few things, but to no avail. Many solutions offer something like /search/my-term/, which I do not want, I want it parameterized.

*.htaccess*

This handles a redirect, but WP returns a 404, which makes sense since there wouldn't be any handler to attach the search query_var.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.+)$
RewriteRule .* /search/?s=%1/? [R,L]
```

*functions.php*

Doesn't seem to be doing anything, still returning a 404. (I have flushed the permalink cache multiple times)

```
    function rewrite_search_url() {
        if (is_search()) {
            //add_rewrite_tag('%s%','([^/]*)');
            add_rewrite_rule(
                '^search/?s=([^/]*)/?',
                'index.php?s=$matches[1]',
                'top'
            );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_search_url' );


    function search_url_rewrite_rule() {
        if ( is_search() && !empty($_GET['s'])) {
            wp_redirect(home_url("/search/?s=") . urlencode(get_query_var('s')));
            exit();
        }   
    }
    add_action('template_redirect', 'search_url_rewrite_rule');
```

Comment: The right way to do this would be to change the URL that the search form is submitted to. How are your search forms added?

Comment: That's a good point, the site was/is using https://fibosearch.com/

Comment: You could also check the add_query_arg function to prepare WordPress for a redirect with query vars.